# Which object file contains the following static templatized "member variable"?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods, static-members, object-files

Say I have the following template class with a static member function that itself instantiates a static variable (which is functionally a static member variable instantiated the first time its containing routine is called):

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    static int& mystatic()
    {
        static int value;

        return value;
    }
};
```

If I use `foo<T>` in multiple translation units for some `T`, into which object file does the compiler put `foo<T>::mystatic::value`? How is this apparent duplication/conflict resolved at link time?

Comment: You might be better off asking this elsewhere, I'm not sure that anyone but a compiler writer could answer this. I think `value` has external linkage, however, because it's not in file scope.

Comment: @dauphic: I'm not sure what you mean by your "`value` has external linkage" remark. In C++ an object defined in a local scope cannot possibly have external linkage. In the above example `value` has *no linkage* from C++ point of view. However, in order to satisfy the requirements of the language, a typical implementation will report `value` as an external symbol in the object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do understand that the your function `mystatic` is a function with external linkage? Which means that the very same conflict exists between multiple definitions of `mystatic` made in different translation units. Also, exactly the same issue can arise without templates: ordinary `inline` functions with external linkage defined in header files can produce the same apparent multiple definition conflict (and the same issue with a local static variable can be reproduced there as well).

In order to resolve such conflicts, all such symbols are labeled by the compiler in some implementation-dependent way. By doing this the compiler communicates to the linker the fact that these symbols can legally end up being defined multiple times. For example, one known implementation puts such symbols into a separate section of object file (sometimes called "COMDAT" section). Other implementations might label such symbols in some other way. When the linker discovers such symbols in multiple object files, instead of reporting a multiple definition error, it chooses *one and only one* of each identical symbol and uses it throughout the entire program. The other copies of each such symbol are discarded by the linker.

One typical consequence of this approach is that your local static variable `value` will have to be included as an external symbol into each object file, despite the fact that it has no linkage from the language point of view. The name of the symbol will usually be composed of the function name `mystatic` and variable name `value` and some other mangling.

In other words, the compiler proper puts both the definition of `mystatic` and the variable `value` into *all* independent object files that use the member function. The linker will later make sure that only one `mystatic` and only one `value` will exist in the linked program. There's probably no way to determine, which original object file supplied the surviving copy (if such distinction even makes sense).

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I realize this is a gritty compiler/linker implementation detail, but a use case had me wondering how the apparent conflict was resolved.